# install a hook for github branch comparison webinterface

Tags: git, github, diff

by installing a [textconv](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Textconv) hook for a file type 
it is possible to modify `git diff` default behaviour 
in a way that it operates on converted data. One application is 
to convert **.odf** content to plain text before comparing.

Is it possible to get the same behavior for the `github` webinterface 
(branch comparison and/or visualization of a commit)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the GitHub team
if hooks for commit visualisation similar to textconv for 'git diff'  are supported and the answer is that they are not.

However, the GitHub-team will think about that suggestion and maybe support something similar in future.